# Get procedure's body

Tags: stored-procedures, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a procedure with sysadmin role. I have granted usage for a new role I have created (role name New_role).

The issue is that users that have permissions to the new_role can't see the procedure body (while executing get_ddl or describe procedures).

How can users that have only permissions on the New_role view/see the procedure's body?

I don't want to give sysadmin to the new role but I would like him to have the option to view the procedure's body

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's not a grant that allows for this particular permission without ownership. However, there are a couple of workarounds. the simplest one is to create a veiw that is owned by the same role that owns of the procedure, which retrieves the procedure definitions. Then you can grant select access to that view to whatever roles you like.

Something like this

```sql
USE SYSADMIN;
USE MY_DB;

CREATE VIEW MY_SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_DEFINITIONS AS
 SELECT PROCEDURE_SCHEMA, PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, PROCEDURE_DEFINITION
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES;
 
GRANT SELECT ON VIEW MY_SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_DEFINITIONS TO NEW_ROLE;
```